# showing data on graph in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django

I am new to Django, I want that user should be able to see total user registered on graph showing progress on the basis of months

view.py

```
def dashboard(request):
    title = 'Dashboard'
    request_url = request.get_full_path()
    username = request.user.username
    local_datetime = datetime.now()
    today = date.today()
    start_of_month = today.replace(day=1)
    end_of_month = start_of_month + relativedelta(day=31)
    monthly_data = (
        Clinic.objects
        .filter(updated__range=(start_of_month, end_of_month))
        .annotate(month=TruncMonth('updated'))
        .values('month')
        .annotate(count=Count('register_clinic_user_id'))
        .order_by('month')
    )
    
    labels = [data['month'].strftime('%B %Y') for data in monthly_data]
    values = [data['count'] for data in monthly_data]

    clinic_list =  Clinic.objects.all()
    content = {
        'title': title, 
        'requesturl': request_url,
        'clinic_list':clinic_list,
        'username':username,
        'current_datetime':local_datetime,
        'graph_data':values,
    }
    return render(request, 'admin/dashboard.html', content)
```

graph.js

```
 new Chart(ctx2, {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
        datasets: [{
            label: "Mobile apps",
            tension: 0.4,
            borderWidth: 0,
            pointRadius: 0,
            borderColor: "#16b385",
            borderWidth: 3,
            backgroundColor: gradientStroke1,
            fill: true,
            data: {{graph_data}},
            maxBarThickness: 6

          },
        ],
      },
```

**error -  syntax error when i write {{graph_data}}**

please let me know the accurate way to show this data on graph

**thanks in advance**

Comment: hi, try putting `{{graph_data}}` inside quotes `''` . i,e : `'{{graph_data}}'` and test again.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it does not show any data on the graph if you have any idea for that Please let me know